# Name 'RandomUnderSampler' is not defined

Tags: python, random, jupyter-notebook, imblearn

I'm trying to use `RandomUnderSampler`. I have correctly installed the `imblearn` module. But still getting the error: "Name 'RandomUnderSampler" is not defined`. Any specific reason for this? Can someone please help

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

#Random under-sampling and over-sampling with imbalanced-learn
def random_under_sampling(X,Y):

    rus = RandomUnderSampler(return_indices=True)
    X_rus, y_rus, id_rus = rus.fit_sample(X, Y)

    print('Removed indexes:', id_rus)

    plot_2d_space(X_rus, y_rus, 'Random under-sampling')
```

[image]

The actual method name

[image]

This is where I called my method
[image]

Comment: Is the library installed correctly?  Are you using `requirements.txt` file?  If not what package manager are you using?

Comment: I don't see how that error could happen.  Was this code cut-and-pasted directly from your script?

Comment: @Sid he isn't getting an `ImportError`, so it doesn't appear to be a problem with the module.

Comment: Hi.. I hope so. It installed without any error. Any way how I can check this? I used anaconda command prompt to install this

Comment: I was asking if you typed the code in this question by hand, or if you cut-and-pasted it directly from your script.

Comment: @jiaJimmy He isn't getting an `ImportError`.

Comment: Yes. I directly cut and paste my code. I'm getting the error NameError: name 'RandomUnderSampler' is not defined

Comment: Strange.  Again, I don't see how that error is possible.  Can you edit the question to include the full error traceback message?

Comment: edited... Please kindly check it

Comment: Is the name `RandomUserSampler` correct?  Is that what's exported by the library?

Comment: That screenshot shows `random_under_sampling()` defined on line 161, so the code in the question is **not** your real code.  Please show us your real code.

Comment: Hi John... The RandomUnderSampler is a method in 'imblearn' right? so I can't see there is an issue. I pasted my code images in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that you are using IPython it is important that you execute first the line importing `imblearn` library (e.g. `Ctrl-Enter`):

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
```

After that the module should get imported and the name of the function is going to be defined.

If this does not work, could you reload the notebook and execute all the statements up until the `random_under_sampling` function to ensure nothing was missed?

Comment: Hi that's correct. I think import imblearn has been not imported correctly. When (e.g. Ctrl-Enter): used, it worked out. Million thanks for everyone